# what formulas should be put for the date by sequence in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, extract-error-message

There is an error message shown up for when I edit the formulas.
we want to sort the ship date by sequence.

parameter field

[image]

error message for "A date-time is required here"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If then else must return the same data type for all branches.

So Convert the dates to a string. For example, ToText({Ship_Date}, 'yyyyMMdd')
and convert the numbers to a string as well. For example,  ToText({PartN}, 0, "")

Comment: Hi, I used this:  if {?Sub Sort} = 'Contract Ship Date' then ToText 
    ({CUST_ORDER_LINE.DESIRED_SHIP_DATE}, 'MM/DD/YYYY,12:00:00AM')
else
if {?Sub Sort} = 'Part ID' then ToText 
    {CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID} 
else {CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_PO_REF};  and the error message highlights   {CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID} 
else {CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_PO_REF} and says "The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula. ...   can you please advise why ?

Comment: added-ToText({CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID},0,"") , and the error message says too many arguments have been given to this function ...

Answer (score 0):

ToText {CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID}
is missing ()

Need to be
ToText({CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID},0,"")

Comment: added-ToText({CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID},0,"") ,  and the error message says too many arguments have been given to this function.